# How to delete/unload all modules mentioned in a list=

Tags: python, del

I want to unload all submodules that belong to a specifc module, because it conflicts with another module. Here's what I do:

```
mainmodule_submodules = [key for key in sys.modules if key.startswith('mainmodule')]
for mainmodule_submodule in mainmodule_submodules:
    del mainmodule_submodule # deletes the variable mainmodule_submodule instead of the submodule that's stored in it
    del sys.modules[mainmodule_submodule]
```

The problem is that this deletes the variable `mainmodule_submodule` that's created by the for loop instead of the module that's stored a the value of `mainmodule_submodule`. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for `del sys.modules[mainmodule_submainmodule]`? `sys.submainmodules` does not exist.

Comment: This is going to create worse problems. Now, instead of these submodules just conflicting with that other module, they'll also start conflicting with alternate versions of themselves as soon as something causes those modules to be loaded again.

Comment: @mkrieger1, yes you‘re right. That was an error from exchanging words. I’ll correct it.

Comment: @user2357112, what would you suggest to do in such a situation alternatively?

Comment: @gernophil: Depends on how and why the original conflict happens. Looking at the issue you linked... if that's what you're running into, then you're probably just screwed until the library maintainers fix it. You'll have to stop using one of the conflicting libraries.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it works just fine on `arm64` architecture (macOS), but not on `x86_64` arch. But it looks like I have to wait through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your exact use case is. Dealing with unloading modules (and possibly reloading them later again) sounds very error-prone. I rather suggest refactoring your code in order to reduce technical debts instead of implementing a workaround.

However, if you want to unload a module just use `del sys.modules[module]` (and `del globals()[module]` if you don't want the imported module available anymore).

Note: I shortened your variable names for better readability in this example context.

```py
import os
import sys

print(os.path.join("a", "b", "c"))

modules = [key for key in sys.modules if key.startswith('os')]

for module in modules:
    if module in sys.modules:
        print(f"Unloading {module}")
        del sys.modules[module]
        if module in globals():
            del globals()[module]

# this should fail
print(os.path.join("a", "b", "c"))
```

Without knowing where your conflicts are, if in your own code, maybe you could avoid conflicts by using aliases.

```py
import os as os_alias

print(os_alias.pathjoin("a", "b", "c"))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. My problem is not the namespace, but to modules that somehow rely on `PyTorch` both, [but the second leads to an error, if PyTorch is loaded independent of it](https://github.com/guillaumekln/faster-whisper/issues/137).